# automount is broken after upgrading MacOS Monterey

Tags: macos, monterey, automount, nfs

I'm having issues with automount with my NFS shares after upgrading to MacOS Monterey 12.3.1.

/etc/auto_master:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
/System/Volumes/Data/mnt auto_mounts
+auto_master            # Use directory service
#/net                   -hosts          -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home                   auto_home       -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers        -fstab
/-                      -static
```

/etc/auto_mounts

```
nas         10.17.24.105:/homes/mynas
```

```
$ sudo automount -vc
automount: /System/Volumes/Data/mnt mounted
automount: /System/Volumes/Data/home updated (/home -> /System/Volumes/Data/home)
automount: no unmounts
$ ls -l /System/Volumes/Data/mnt/
total 0
ls: fts_read: Input/output error
```

Any ideas?  I have already tried a bunch of things, including manually mounting the shares with `mount -t nfs`.

Comment: Is the share really an NFS share? If not, the format of your `auto_mounts` is wrong and your entry is going to get treated as an NFS share. See `man auto_master` sections `AUTOMOUNTER MAP` on the format for SMB/CIFS shares.

Comment: yes, definitely are NFS shares.  I actually have 2 separate NFS shares on different servers.  I can manually mount those using the 'mount -t nfs' command.

Answer (score 0):

does the manual `mount -t nfs blah.blah:/blah` end up also being mounted to `/homes/`?

when operating with SIP active you shouldn't be allowed to mount a filesystem to a directory at `/` on your boot volume unless you've also configured `/etc/synthetic.conf` to create those directories you'll mount filesystems at.

i don't use macOS automount these days but unless /home/mynas is there at boot nothing can be hitched to it. my creative workstation has a local zpool (two pairs of mirrored 4TB NVMe drives in a thunderbolt 3 "jbod" of sorts) and here's an example of how i've configured for (direct-attached mind you but similar constraints) my zpool in `/etc/synthetic.conf`:

```
# zpool cascade:
#

av      cascade/av
devel       cascade/developer
it      cascade/it
phones      cascade/it/deviceManagement
people      cascade/people
```

it'll create the directories on boot. i also have some convience options like my dropbox folder being available at /dropbox:

```
dropbox     Volumes/µ/fs/Dropbox
```

etc. i use `/onedrive/` on my employer-provided workstation.

if the directory isn't there automount probably can't mount to it. and if automount can't mount to it, the mount will fail. before i knew how to do this the right way with `/etc/synthetic.conf` i hacked out some crazy shit in an unlocked unsealed APFS volume and i'm pretty sure it caused other problems later so i was pretty excited to learn about that file!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file /etc/auto_nas content is incomplete.
try:  nas   -rw 10.17.24.105:/homes/mynas